# JPanels not showing even though frame is visible

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, game-development

I am creating a pause screen for a 2048 game.I am just trying to add my Panels to a JFrame with different components on each panel, but none of the panels show on my laptop. However, on my friends laptop it runs just fine, they are no error messages when it runs.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
//@Author: Nathan

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

    public class main{

        public main(){

            //Creating Frame
            JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
            mainFrame.setResizable(false);
            mainFrame.setTitle("Pause");
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mainFrame.setLayout(null);
            mainFrame.setSize(600, 600);
            mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        

            //Creating colour variables
            Color c = new Color(223, 146, 97);

            //Adding Panels
            JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
            northPanel.setBackground(c);
            northPanel.setBounds(0, 0,600, 50 );

            JPanel upperPanel = new JPanel();
            upperPanel.setBackground(c);
            upperPanel.setBounds(0, 50, 200, 550);

            JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
            centerPanel.setBackground(c);
            centerPanel.setBounds(0 , 50 , 300 ,550);

          //Creating Icons for buttons
            ImageIcon infoIcon = new ImageIcon("./Icons/info.png");
            ImageIcon themeIcon = new ImageIcon("./Icons/paint.png");
            ImageIcon volumeOn = new ImageIcon("./Icons/volume.png");
            ImageIcon volumeOff =new ImageIcon("./Icons/volumeOff.png"); 
        
            //Creating Componenets

            Font Titlefont = new Font("SansSerrif", Font.PLAIN, 20);
        
             JLabel pauseTitle = new JLabel("2048");
             pauseTitle.setFont(Titlefont);

             JButton themeButton = new JButton(themeIcon);
             themeButton.setBackground(c);
             themeButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
         
             JButton volumeButton = new JButton(volumeOn);
             volumeButton.setBackground(c);
 
             JButton infoButton = new JButton(infoIcon);
             infoButton.setBackground(c);
 
             JButton playButton = new JButton("PLAY");
             JButton resetButton = new JButton("RESET");
             JButton homeButton = new JButton("HOME");

            //Adding panels to mainframe
            mainFrame.add(northPanel);
            mainFrame.add(upperPanel);
            mainFrame.add(centerPanel); 

            //Adding Components to panels
            northPanel.add(pauseTitle); 

            upperPanel.add(themeButton);
            upperPanel.add(volumeButton);
            upperPanel.add(infoButton);

            centerPanel.add(playButton);
            centerPanel.add(resetButton);
            centerPanel.add(homeButton);
 
        }

        public static void main(String [] args){
           new main();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at where you set the JFrame visible. Then look at where you add components to it. It's not a good idea to render the GUI *before* setting it up . Having said that, you should avoid use of null layout and use of `setBounds(...)` for component placement as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain.

Comment: also, many Swing Components have a warning: "**Warning:** Swing is not thread safe. For more information see [Swing's Threading Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading).", that means: new main()` -> `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(main::new)`